# Divisibility question: if $a=be+r$, then $e$ $= ⌊\frac{a}{b}⌋$

Tags: divisibility

If  $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, then I know that $ a=be+r$, where $e\in \Bbb Z$ and $r$ is the remainder. How can I prove that  $e$ is equal to  $⌊\frac ab⌋$?

I'm missing this step in another proof and I really don't know how to prove it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a = be+r$ and $r<b$ so
$$
be\le a = be+r<be+b = (e+1)b;\\
e\le \frac ab< e+1
$$
and as $e\in\Bbb Z$, $$
e = [\frac ab]
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\,\  &&0 \le\overbrace{ a-be}^{\textstyle r}\, <\, b\\
\overset{\div\, b} \iff &&  0 \le a/b-e < 1\\
\overset{+\,e}\iff &&   e  \le a/b < e+1\\[.3em]
\iff &&   e =\lfloor a/b\rfloor
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Thus the (last) floor inequality arises from scaling and shifting the (first) remainder inequality, i.e. $\, x\mapsto x/b + e\ \ $